# firebaselist adapter can't see text

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

every thing works good but the text doens't appear although the list add item when i add to ref a new child,  i have tried to change R.layout.simple_list_item_1 but it doesn't work

```
Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://shoppinglist-fahmi.firebaseio.com/msg");
    FirebaseListAdapter<String> listAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this,String.class, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,ref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) {
}
    };
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement `populateView()` to pass the value of `s` into the `view`:

```
protected void populateView(View view, String s, int i) {
  ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(s);
}
```